# How to update a LiveData's value after overwrite the database file?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I'm building an app with MVVM. The ListVideoPartsActivity has a RecyclerView that it's populated from a LiveData in the ViewModel through a local Database using Room.

ListVideoPartsActivity.kt

```
viewModel.allVideosWithParts.observe(this) { videosWithParts ->
    videosWithParts.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
}
```

ListVideoPartsViewModel.kt

```
var allVideosWithParts: LiveData<List<VideoWithParts>> = videoPartRepository.observeAllVideosWithParts()
```

DefaultVideoPartRepository.kt

```
override fun observeAllVideosWithParts(): LiveData<List<VideoWithParts>> {
    return videoPartDao.getVideosWithParts().asLiveData()
}
```

VideoPartDao.kt

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM video_table")
fun getVideosWithParts(): Flow<List<VideoWithParts>>
```

Up to this point everything works perfect, but I added an Import/export database file functionality.

VideoPartDatabase.kt

```
abstract class VideoPartDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun videoPartDao(): VideoPartDao

companion object {
    private const val database_name = "video_part_db"
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: VideoPartDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): VideoPartDatabase {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance =
                Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    VideoPartDatabase::class.java,
                    database_name
                )
                    .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                    .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }

    private const val DB_FILEPATH = "/data/data/mypackage/databases/video_part_db"

    fun exportDatabase(context: Context): Boolean {
        return copyFile(File(DB_FILEPATH), File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), FileManager.getFileNameComplete()), context)
    }

    private fun copyFile(source: File, destination: File, context: Context): Boolean {
        try {
            FileUtils.copy(FileInputStream(source), FileOutputStream(destination))
            return true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return false
    }

    fun importDatabase(context: Context, fileImportName: String): Boolean {
        return copyFile(File(getBackUpFolderPath(context)?.absolutePath, fileImportName), File(DB_FILEPATH), context)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it's the one that worked best for me.
The thing is that when I import a database file, the RecyclerView and LiveData in the ViewModel doesn't change. I need to do, for example, an update to one item from the RecyclerView for the ViewModel to get the data changes from the import.

So, my question is, which would be the best way to make the data in the LiveData to get updated after a database file import?